# Swift UITableView Show Different Cell Every 10th Cell

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, cell

I'm trying to show a different cell after every 10 cells using two arrays: "ads" and "requests"
I want my TableView to look like this:

```
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Request"
"Ad"
"Request"
"Request"
...
```

I know how to do an ad but not how to order the cells like this using two arrays. Not at all :/
Any suggestions how to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
func loadAds()
    {
        Api.adApi.observeAds
        {
            (ad) in
            self.list = self.requests
            for i in stride(from: self.adInterval, to: self.requests.count, by: self.adInterval).reversed()
            {
                // not getting executed
                print("test1")
                self.list.insert(ad, at: i)
            }
            // getting executed
            print("test2")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches:

1. One (described by others) is to have your two arrays and have the `UITableViewDataSource` methods figure out which cell to dequeue based upon the `indexPath.row % 10`.

   The problem here, IMHO, is that you end up with ugly logic in your data source methods, mapping an `indexPath.row` to the appropriate row in your response array or ad arrays.

   So, I'd suggest utility functions, `dataRow` and `adRow` to reverse engineer what the index is in the associated array (returning `nil` if the `IndexPath` isn't relevant):

   ```
   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

       private func dataRow(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int? {
           let (quotient, remainder) = (indexPath.row + 1).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: adInterval)
           if remainder == 0 { return nil }
           return quotient * (adInterval - 1) + remainder - 1
       }

       private func adRow(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int? {
           let (quotient, remainder) = (indexPath.row + 1).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: adInterval)
           if remainder != 0 { return nil }
           return quotient - 1
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return objects.count + ads.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           if let row = dataRow(for: indexPath) {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
               let object = objects[row]
               // configure cell using model data, `object`
               return cell
           } else if let row = adRow(for: indexPath) {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath)
               let ad = ads[row]
               // configure cell using ad data, `ad`
               return cell
           }

           fatalError("Did not find data or ad for cell: Should never get here")
       }

   }
   ```

   BTW, note that I'm not just doing `indexPath.row % 10` (because I don't want the first thing shown to be an ad). So I'm actually doing `(indexPath.row + 1) % 10`.
2. The other approach, is to have a single view model structure representative of the consolidated list of model objects and ads. For example, imagine I had model objects for items in my list and for ads:

   ```
   protocol Listable { }

   /// An Item is a model object for "real" objects to be shown in table 

   struct Item: Listable {
       let string: String
       let imageURL: URL
   }

   /// An Ad is a model object for advertisement to be inserted into table

   struct Ad: Listable {
       let string: String
   }
   ```

   Then, given my list of items, I can then insert my ads, building a consolidated list of items and ads:

   ```
   var items: [Item]! = ...
   var list: [Listable]!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // build consolidated list of items and ads

       list = items
       for i in stride(from: adInterval, to: items.count, by: adInterval).reversed() {
           list.insert(Ad(...), at: i)
       }
   }
   ```

   Then the `UITableViewDataSource` methods don't have to do any math to figure out which array a particular listing is, but rather, just see which type it is and act accordingly:

   ```
   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return list.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let listing = list[indexPath.row]

           if let item = listing as? Item {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
               // configure cell using `item`
               return cell
           } else if let ad = listing as? Ad {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath)
               // configure cell using `ad`
               return cell
           }

           fatalError("Did not find data or ad for cell: Should never get here")
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, one last question. My cells are not displaying, I added new code to my question, I would really appreciate it if you'd take a look.

Comment: The requests array is the items array in your code and the adinterval is an int. Is that wrong? I know I sound kinda dumb, but Im pretty new to this stuff :D

Comment: Right, so I'm asking you to confirm (a) how many items are in your array (i.e. `self.requests.count`); and (b) what your `adInterval` was (I used 10). The way I'm inserting ads, it will only do it if there are 10 or more items in  `requests`. I also wanted to confirm that your array wasn't empty. I also wanted to confirm that you were using a reasonable value for `adInterval`. That's why I asked. Also, because you're not calling `reloadData()`, it won't reload the table once your API call was done, which is why I suggested you make sure to call that in your API closure.

Comment: Also make sure that the API closure is running on the main queue, and if not, dispatch everything in that closure to the main queue with `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`.

Comment: Okay, it's kinda working now, but the app crashes as soon as i scroll to the bottom of the TableView (ErrorMessage: index out of range)

Comment: Sounds like a problem in [`tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview). Make sure that's returning `return list.count`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574039/swift-uitableview-every-nth-cell-different

Answer (score 3):

In [cellForRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) just check `if indexPath.row % 10 == 0`. If it does then you are on a multiple of 10. Then all you need to do is instantiate a difference cell.  You'll also need to keep track of the index for the request data array and the ad data array. You can do something like this.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var requestIndex = 0
    var adIndex = 0

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row % 10 != 0 || indexPath.row == 0 {
            requestIndex += 1
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RequestCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestCell
            // configure cell with requestIndex
            // cell.imageView.image = requestDataArray[requestIndex].image
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCell
            adIndex += 1
            // configure cell with adIndex
            // cell.imageView.image = adDataArray[adIndex].image
            return cell
    }
}
```

You could also keep track of the indices using some basic math

```
if indexPath.row % 10 != 0 {
    let requestIndex = indexPath.row - (indexPath.row / 10) // current indexPath - the number of adds already displayed
}
else {
    let adIndex = (indexPath.row / 10) + 1 // number of previously displayed ads plus one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for single ad that will be repeated but this will cost you array[index%10] value will not be displayed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row % 10 == 0 {

    //return ads cell
    }
    else{
    //normal cell
    }


    }
```

if we have multiple ads we could insert ads in our array of model every nth value and put extra property say like containAds so we check like this

```
  if modelArray[indexPath.row].cotainAds {
      //return ads cell
     }
else {
 //return normal cell
}
```

so the whole operation is about modifying original array by inserting ads in specific order